# After Upgrading Native script ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/webpack/android-app-components-loader'

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, code-sharing

I am using Code-sharing project Native-Script with Angular
After Upgrading Native script to the latest version I got

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/webpack/android-app-components-loader'
```

My Angular Project works but I got the problem when I try

```
tns run android
```

This is my

```
tns info
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 6.8.0 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-core-modules has 6.6.0-next-2020-05-08-112112-01 version and is up to date.
√ Component @nativescript/core has 7.0.0-rc.52 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-android has 6.5.3 version and is up to date.
× Component tns-ios is not installed.
```

Could Anyone help me?